# Swing, update textfield value within a for

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I'm trying to update my Java Swing form within a for. I tried many ways, but it wasn't working. This is what I last tried:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    jTextField1.setText("" + i);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update a jLabel every time with a while loop with a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251675/how-to-update-a-jlabel-every-time-with-a-while-loop-with-a-delay) (and of dozens of other similar questions)

Comment: Thanks for replies. I'll see what I can do with Timer. The problem is that I make Math calculations in a loop, so I don't know how to implement this with Timer.

Comment: @SpartakusMd Then, SwingWorker is your friend. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010990/changing-jtextfields-text-while-iterating-or-inside-a-loop/16011226#16011226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make your jTextField1 variable 'final' but you can use a local variable declared final and set to your jTextField1 variable as I showed below...I used many times such approach in my coding, it works...

```
final jTextField local_var = jTextField1;
```

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

`for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        local_var.setText("" + i);

  }});`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to update component from external thread. In general, Swing is not thread safe, for more details take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). Regarding to your code, try follow this approach:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            jTextField1.setText("" + i);
        }
    });
}
```

Variable `jTextField1` must be declared as `final`.

Comment: Just tried that. If I declare `jTextField1` as `final` then initialisation of the field fails. Can't assign value to final variables.

Comment: You can create class which  implements <code>Runnable</code> and takes <code>jTextField1</code> as parameter.