# Need a timed panel.repaint();

Tags: java, swing, sleep, repaint

I want my code to paint a panel, wait 1 second. Edit the panel by executing the function nextGen(); and repaint the panel. I want this function to happen 5 times. The problem is, everytime I try to do a try/catch thing with thread.sleep(), it "skips" over repaint, does nextGen(); and sleeps. Please help!

```
button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        nextGen();
                        panel.repaint();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/182422/85421 ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074427/85421 ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/7217210/85421 ; https://stackoverflow.com/q/16404023/85421 ; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Swing `Timer`...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    private int count;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        nextGen();
        panel.repaint();
        count++;
        if (count >= 5) {
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
timer.start();
```

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the reason why you're having this particular issue and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details about Swing `Timer`

Comment: :/ Did you forget to import `javax.swing.Timer`?  Did you read the linked docs?  Did you look at the linked examples?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped! but if I were to make it a start/stop button, how would I do it?

Comment: You would need to make the reference to `Timer` an instance field, so I could be accessed in a large scope.  Then you can simply call `start`/`stop` as needed

Comment: I still don't quite understand.

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408678/adding-resume-function-to-stopwatch/50409049#50409049)